# Visual Studio or IIS bug?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis

I don't really know how to go about figuring out this issue, so I hope that someone can piece together my situation and give me some guidance.

I've been working on a site, I was observing some odd behavior, like changing some text on a page didn't reflect when I debugged.  The same happened today, I added a hyperlink to a gridview, and when I tried to set the URL in the code behind, I was getting errors saying that it couldn't find the control I had created in the aspx. The debugger was hitting my breakpoints too.  I checked in my code, and tried it on another dev machine, it worked perfectly fine there.  I'm not certain at all what's causing the issue, but it seems like when I debug, I'm running a different version of the source, but that doesn't explain to me how I can hit debugging points.  Any help would be great.

Comment: how are you deploying it? be sure that the files were not cached and do a build > clean solution then a build > rebuild solution and see if it works.

Comment: Visusal studio stores user preferences in a .suo file in the directory of your salution. if u delete this file and restart, all user setting should be reset for this project. This seem to fix a lot of problems and just might work for this one. (;

Comment: I'll try the user preference thing.  I have cleaned and rebuilt, that didn't work.

Comment: Deleting the .suo file didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl+F5 in the browser to clear it cache.

If that doesn't help, restart iis.

Finally clearing and rebuilding the solution can help as well.

Comment: I tried each of these steps, and the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clear ASP.NET cache?

Just delete files in `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\{.NET Version}\Temporary ASP.NET Files\{your website}` or `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\{.NET Version}\Temporary ASP.NET Files\{your website}`